# Using Javascript to detect real text, not HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tinymce

I'm having an issue where I use a WYSIWYG editor (TinyMCE) to save content into the database, and sometimes values get saved that don't real content, but only tags like:

```
<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
```

which isn't real content.

So my application can't tell when there's real content versus some invisible HTML tags.

How can I use JS to reliably detect when there's real content, or invisible tags? Note that simple checks for "`<br>`" won't work because additional attributes like `data-mce-bogus="1"` may exist, and others I haven't seen before.

Ideally my editor will detect this when content is updated, and save an empty string in the DB if there's no "real" content detected. My app is in Angular JS, so I need it in JS, not server-side.

Comment: You may need to define "real content". Do you mean you're typing in raw HTML into TinyMCE editor and it's stripping them out? Or to simplify that: what are you typing into TinyMCE, what result are you getting, and what is the expected result?

Comment: If jQuery is available you can use [$.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the tags without tuching their content and check if there is something left.

```
var text = '<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>';

var clearRegexp = /<[^>]+>/g;

text = text.replace(clearRegexp, "");

var hasContent = text.trim() != "";
```